How to measure user time and system time for very fast function like mmap() in C?
I only want to know the user time and system time for mmap() rather than error checking or munmap().
For now my solution is:
void measure_mmap_time(double *user_time, double *system_time) {
    struct rusage start, end;
    int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE); 
    double total_user_time = 0;
    double total_system_time = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start); 
        // Map a page of memory
        void *addr = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end); 
        
        if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        if (munmap(addr, pagesize) == -1) {
            perror("munmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
       
        // Calculate user and system time for this iteration
        total_user_time += get_time_diff(start.ru_utime, end.ru_utime);
        total_system_time += get_time_diff(start.ru_stime, end.ru_stime);
    }

    *user_time = total_user_time / NUM_ITERATIONS;
    *system_time = total_system_time / NUM_ITERATIONS;
}

But it would be more ideal if I can put getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start) and getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end) outside of the loop while also have munmap() inside the loop. Is it possible?
To discount the effects of the loop and munmap(), I have a new function. Is it reasonable to do so?
void measure_mmap_time(double *user_time, double *system_time) {
    struct rusage start, end;
    int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE); 
    double total_user_time = 0;
    double total_system_time = 0;

    void *addresses[NUM_ITERATIONS];

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start); 
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        // Map a page of memory
        addresses[i] = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end); 

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        if (munmap(addresses[i], pagesize) == -1) {
            perror("munmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
       
    // Calculate user and system time for this iteration
    total_user_time = get_time_diff(start.ru_utime, end.ru_utime);
    total_system_time = get_time_diff(start.ru_stime, end.ru_stime);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end);

    double total_user_time2 = get_time_diff(start.ru_utime, end.ru_utime);
    double total_system_time2 = get_time_diff(start.ru_stime, end.ru_stime);

    *user_time = (total_user_time - total_user_time2) / NUM_ITERATIONS;
    *system_time = (total_system_time - total_system_time2) / NUM_ITERATIONS;
}


Would you be okay with remapping the same memory? If you mmap once before the loop, then remap that same memory over and over within the loop with MAP_FIXED, it's legal, and doesn't require unmapping to avoid a leak. Not sure if that's going to measure what you want, but most of the work here is the system call anyway.

Can you use a profiling tool rather than writing your own code?

Do 1000 maps of different pages in a loop, measuring the time for the whole loop, not each iteration. After that, you can unmap the pages and repeat to get statistical measurements.

@EricPostpischil I assume I need to use the memory address returned from mmap() to unmap in each iteration. If so, how can I unmap after the loop?

@union77: Remember the addresses in an array.

@EricPostpischil Sorry I'm still confused. But when you map in the loop, you also need to put the address in the array in the loop. In this case, when I measure the time for whole loop, I have both mmap and the time to put the addresses in the array

@union77: The time to store one element in an array is trivial compared to a system call. Your loop already contains other instructions, for ++i and i < NUM_ITERATIONS. If you want to discount those, you have extra work to do and need a model of how they interact with the mmap.

@EricPostpischil I updated my code! I tried to use your idea plus some of my improvisation. Does the new code make sense to you?
